# MySQL: why shows select "columnname" shows more data than select *

Tags: mysql, zabbix

in a mysql table (zabbix) there is a table called "maintenances" with this structure:

| maintenanceid | name | maintenance_type | description | active_since | active_till | tags_evaltype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | 0 |  | 1647298800 | 2057612400 | 0 |
| 124 | YYYYYYYYYYYYYY | 0 |  | 1671656400 | 1671663600 | 0 |

when i run this command:

```
SELECT * FROM maintenances;
```

i got a result of 18 rows:

> 18 rows in set (0.001 sec)

when i run this command:

```
SELECT name FROM maintenances;
```

i got a result of 37 rows:

> 37 rows in set (0.001 sec)

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `maintenances` (
  `maintenanceid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `maintenance_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `active_since` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `active_till` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `tags_evaltype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`maintenanceid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `maintenances_2` (`name`),
  KEY `maintenances_1` (`active_since`,`active_till`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

how is that possible? i thought with "select * from x" mysql shows me all entries?

thanks to luuk, command

```
CHECK TABLE maintenances;
```

shows a corruption:

| Table | Op | Msg_type | Msg_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zabbix.maintenances | check | Warning | InnoDB: Index 'maintenances_2' contains 37 entries, should be 18. |
| zabbix.maintenances | check | error | Corrupt |

regards,
daniel

mysql version:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.18-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu

Comment: This is indeed not possible. So, something else is going on. But, with the information given, it is almost impossible to help you. We would need the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` at least, and any and all extra information you are leaving out.

Comment: Check these queries from CLI, not from any other client.

Comment: What is the output of: `CHECK TABLE maintenances;` ?  (see: [CHECK TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/check-table.html))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Presumably the query with `name` can be got from scanning the unique index whereas the one with `*` would require a table scan so maybe some corruption meaning they are not in synch

Answer (score 0):

thank you all.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE maintenances;
```

solved the corruption.